# Secure payment by CyberSource and Merchant Reference Code

Tags: extensions, payment-gateway, third-party-module, enterprise-1.14, merchant

Lately, as of just a couple days ago our Merchant Reference Code in our EE 1.14 have been really wonky.

[image]

Notice the 32 digit alpha-numeric code that is being generated.

Here's what it should look like:

[image]

Correct: 100204738

INCorrect: fc01c106bbf410bffda5ba80a9a982b9

We are currently using the magedelight cybersource plugin. Nothing has really changed in the past couple days. No code pushes to production or anything like that.

The only major change I've made is installing a CDN to server /skin /media /js.

It appeared to happen the same day as the CDN installation. Although, I've now reverted the CDB installation back to the standard magento configuration and it's still causing issues.

Has anybody experienced this before? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

If I changed the array using array_splice would that eventually send the updated Merchant Reference Code or is it just being echo'ed or printed on adminthtml/default/default/template/md/cybersource/cc.phtml